# How can I set different log locations with static logger

Tags: c++, logging, static, mfc

I have a MFC C++ library that is called from another program. Essentially my library is just a big ol class for a OPOS device. My OPOS class has many other classes that make a call to a static logger. The logger either outputs to a file or to the console (depending on registry setting) Well the other day someone made 2 instances of the class and set logging of instance 1 to log1.log and instance 2 to log2.log

Well since my logging is static part of instance 1 logged to log1. When instance 2 was made both instance 1 and instance 2 now write to log2. I was asked if that could be fixed. I got to thiking about it and I can't figure out how I would do that. I've been doing C++ for about a year now and so I'm not super well versed in it and just can't think of a solution. Any tips?

A little about what i've done to try is that I've checked the CurrentThread, the CurrentProcess, the incoming DispatchID and they are always the same. Any other suggestions?

Although I don't like the idea of the amount of work it would do if I had to change my logging from static to non-static I suppose if it was the only way to do it I would.

Comment: "big ol class"  I smell a design fail.

Comment: @JohnDibling nah, that is just me :) To make a OPOS service object you basically extend the appropriate interface. In my case it is MSR. The OPOS interfaces in general (and in my opinion) are large. Compared to my interfaces that have maybe 2 or 3 methods. Since my MSR device has many functions I break the other functions up into smaller classes. Such as lights, and beeps, and properties.

Comment: Well, it might be my neighbor's lunch that I smell.  I don't know what OPOS or MSR means, so I'll defer.

Comment: @JohnDibling if you have heard of POS (Point-Of-Sale) then you've seen 1/3 of the OPOS Common Control Objects. MSR is Magnetic Stripe Reader. That part is unimportant to the problem at hand though. I'm more concerned with how to get each instance of my MSR class to use its own logging.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are maintaining the log file/console handle within the static logging class, you would need to either make the logging non-static or let the log-open return a handle which the calling routines subsequently pass to the log-write methods.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this handle way (I know what a handle is though) Before i mark your answer as what i'm going to try to do would you mind posting a small blippet of what you mean? It sounds like a great idea hence why I put a +1

Comment: I'm not very sure what you are looking for, this is a short summary of what I would do:
Open: `FILE *fLog = _tfsopen(sFileName, _T("a+tc"), _SH_DENYWR); return fLog;`
Write: `_fputts(sLogContents, fLog);`

Comment: Thank you for that. I will give it a shot and see what happens